# How to call all values in nested JSON data (d3js)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, visualization, panel-data

I have data that is structured as JSON that looks like this (the real data is much larger and each instance has many more variables and attributes):

```
var json = [
{
    "CLIN": "1",
    "cost": 257,
},
{
    "CLIN": "1",
    "cost": 846,
},
{
    "CLIN": "2",
    "cost": 162         
},
{
    "CLIN": "2",
    "cost": 984
}]
```

This is what my JS code looks like:

```
   <script>
        var margin = {top: 20, right: 160, bottom: 35, left: 30};

        var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var svg = d3.select('body')
                    .append('svg')
                    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate('+ margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var dataByCLIN = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) {return d.CLIN; })
            .entries(json);

  </script>
```

This successfully nests the data by the CLIN attribute. However, when I attempt to pass all four variables to create four rectangles for my bargraph, it does not return any values

```
        var bars = svg.selectAll('rect')
                    .data(dataByCLIN)
                    .enter()
                        .append('rect')
                        .attr('width', function(d) { return d.values.cost; })
                        .attr('height', 10)
                        .attr('y', function(d, i) { return i * 20; });
```

If I run the code below with various array selections:

```
console.log(dataByCLIN[0].values[0].cost)
```

It returns the values I need, but the code:

```
.attr('width', function(d, i, j) { return d[i].values[j].cost;
```

is invalid. The console throws the error

```
Cannot read property 'values' of undefined
```

I know how to select the data I need, but not the right formatting to pass that data to the d3 function.

Comment: To clarify, I need to be able to call data like this for the purpose of creating a stacked bar chart with CLIN on the x-axis and using a third, qualitative attribute in each entry for color coding. Otherwise I would skip nesting entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use a `for/forEach` for your data `dataByCLIN` and create `rects` inside each loop like this:

```
var bars = svg.selectAll('.rects');
dataByCLIN.forEach(function(d,i1) {
  bars.data(d.values).enter().append('rect').attr('class', 'rects')
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      return d.cost;
    })
    .attr('height', 10)
    .attr('y', function(d, i) {
      return (i+i1+i1+1) * 20 - 20;
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle:

```js
var json = [{
    "CLIN": "1",
    "cost": 257,
  },
  {
    "CLIN": "1",
    "cost": 846,
  },
  {
    "CLIN": "2",
    "cost": 162

  },
  {
    "CLIN": "2",
    "cost": 984
  }
];


var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 160,
  bottom: 35,
  left: 30
};

var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var dataByCLIN = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.CLIN;
  })
  .entries(json);

var bars = svg.selectAll('.rects');
dataByCLIN.forEach(function(d, i1) {
  bars.data(d.values).enter().append('rect').attr('class', 'rects')
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      return d.cost;
    })
    .attr('height', 10)
    .attr('y', function(d, i) {
      return (i + i1 + i1 + 1) * 20 - 20;
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tweaked it a little to get the stacking right, but it calls all the values in a logical order that I can work with. Thank you so much.